# Look closest value in column C from column A Excel array formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have the numbers in Column A and corresponding codes in B. Now for numbers in C I want to search for each one the closest value in A and show its value of B.
So I use the following array formula in D2 and it works for almost all cases, but is printing wrong value for last value in column C (38909). The closest value for 38909 in column A is 38909 and its related code is PUK, but is printing JIM that is related with the value 3890947021.

May somebody help me to fix the formula to match all cases in this table please. Thanks

Formula I have is:

```
=IF($C2="","",IFERROR(LOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,
SEARCH(IF(LEN($A$2:$A$15)>LEN($C2),"|"
&LEFT($A$2:$A$15,LEN($C2)),"|"
&$A$2:$A$15),"|"&$C2),
$B$2:$B$15),"NOT FOUND"))
```

Table

```
[A]         [B]     [C]         [D]          [E] 
CC          CODE    NUMBERS     RESULT NOW   RESULT EXPECTED
237         CMR     18763044    JAM          JAM
230         MUS     187635      JAM          JAM
61          AUS     23092       MUS          MUS
31          NLD     3162        NLD          NLD
599         ANT     38050       NOT FOUND    NOT FOUND
358         FIN     33          FRA          FRA
33751       FRA     49185       NOT FOUND    NOT FOUND
65          SGP     51078       NOT FOUND    NOT FOUND
1721        SXM     1246        BRB          BRB
1876        JAM     389094702   JIM          JIM
81          JPN     38909       JIM          PUK
124622      BRB
38909       PUK
3890947021  JIM
```

**Update**

After some hours I was able to get this formula that works if the values in column A are sorted ascending.

```
=IF($C2="","",IFERROR(
LOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,
SEARCH(
IF(OR($A$2:$A$15=$C2),"|"&$A$2:$A$15,
IF(LEN($A$2:$A$15)>LEN($C2),
"|"&LEFT($A$2:$A$15,LEN($C2)),
"|"&$A$2:$A$15)),
"|"&$C2),$B$2:$B$15),"NOT FOUND"))
```

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: What do you mean by "closest"? It does not appear to be numerically closest.

Comment: Perhaps Microsoft's `fuzzy match` add-in would be of value to you.

Comment: With closest I mean the value with closest prefix. I hope make sense

Comment: @eesia puts her finger on the problem exactly. Even identifying the longest match wouldn't help much because there can still be ties. You could improve it a bit by identifying exact matches first, and also showing which ones have multiple matches of the same length..

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your formula correctly it does exactly what it should. Problem is that 38909 is in 3890947021. For 38909 your formula had two possible matches so it gives you the last one. If you change the order in your column A and B like:

```
[A]         [B]
CC          CODE
237         CMR
230         MUS
61          AUS
31          NLD
599         ANT
358         FIN
33751       FRA
65          SGP
1721        SXM
1876        JAM
81          JPN
124622      BRB
3890947021  JIM
38909       PUK
```

you'll get PUK for both numbers 3890947021 and 38909. The only way I see is to add another condition to the formula which would check if there is exact match in column A but it still wouldn't solve your problem if the order were reverse.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It's a kind of complex then, since I need to sort in certain way first like I understand you.

Comment: Or you can try and do it using macro.

Comment: I made an update in my post. I was able to get a formula that seems to work. Thanks